# Is it possible to use an iPhone as a wired modem, connecting to a PC via Lightning to Ethernet adapter?

Tags: ethernet, iphone, tethering

There are Lightning to Ethernet adapters, originally meant to connect iPhone or iPhone to an ethernet cable. Alternatively, there are adapters that connect female USB to male ethernet cable.

Is it possible to use those to connect an iPhone to a computer, so that the computer will be able to access the internet via ethernet?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to connect wirelessly? You are just asking to use the phone as a hotspot, with a wire, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works in most cases. But I have this wonky notebook that won't connect to WiFi, just ethernet connection. Probably a hardware defect, but it isn't worth it to have it repaired, due to its age.